# Angular 11 Material DataSource without further Requests to the Server

Tags: angular-material

I've been playing around with the [example table-schematic](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#table-schematic) for the Material Design [version: 11.0.3] table.

Basically i want to make a request, take the response and display it with the options to sort and limit the displayed items (pagination).

It works fine if I just replace the content of the connect function with "return a mapped Observable of the Response" but then the sorting and pagination obviously don't work anymore (since they are deleted) and i can't figure out how to make them work.

I assume the example pagination and sorting requires the data to be already present when the page loads/initializes (e.g. with a static Array).
Putting the request in the connect() function, saving the objects of the response to a variable and subscribing does work. However the page does not update after filling the initially empty array with data until sorting or pagination settings change. Which would make sense to me.

My question is, how do i get the data in there once and use the same data for pagination and sorting.
Can I even use the schematic in this case or is it misleading?

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a `MatTableDataSource` using an array of data, and then it will handle paging, filtering, and sorting locally and not try to fetch any more data.

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/nleleddqmel?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-overview-example.ts

This example creates the data array locally, but you would instead use the response from your server request.

Comment: Thanks, that example is more helpful. :)